# GA4 add_to_cart items parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The GA4 ref docs are not very clear what the `items` parameter is for the `add_to_cart` event.

Is it the cart after the product has been added (I mean, this parameter is a list) or is it just an array with one item - the product that was just added?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm#add_to_cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` must be an `array` with one **OR** multiple items depending on how the shop system/user journey works (most of the time it would contain a single product that got added to the cart). The crucial part would be to have either the `item_id` or `item_name` keys along with the `quantity` key that represents your product(s). If no `quantity` is defined, then GA4 would consider quantity = 1.